# Generate keyrings with gpg2

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to generate keyring using gpg2, however I have problem with .secring.gpg because it is not created.

This is what I've tried, I created a file app.batch

```
%echo Generating a configuration OpenPGP key
Key-Type: default
Subkey-Type: default
Name-Real: myapp
Name-Comment: myapp configuration key
Name-Email: app@example.com
Expire-Date: 0
%pubring .pubring.gpg
%secring .secring.gpg
%commit
%echo done
```

Then, I run the following command

```
gpg2 --batch --armor --gen-key app.batch
```

However, just .pubring.gpg file is created, I got no errors. 
I'm doing this because I need to encrypt data in a etcd server (http://xordataexchange.github.io/crypt/)

Comment: For GnuPG 2.1 and later ‘%secring’ is a no-op.